# Syntax Error in python code for read sensor data through url and store into drive in .csv format

Tags: pi-3, python-3

I was writing a python script to collect data remotely from plc through URL and store those data into my drive in CSV format. I have used the **urllib3** module to collect data from the remote device. The problem is whenever I am trying to decode those raw data which is coming from the remote device through URL using this code `int(b.decode(("utf-8").spilt('RVI')[1].spilt('*')[0], 16)` the compiler shows a syntax error, but I didn't find anything wrong in this code. I am new to Python as well as Raspberry Pi, please help me to sort out the error.

My full code is

```
import os
import time
from time import sleep
import datetime
import urllib3


def readVoltage():
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    responce = http.request('GET', 'http://northam.ddns.net:9080?HOSTLINK/RVIY*')
    responce1 = http.request('GET', 'http://northam.ddns.net:9080/HOSTLINK/RVIA*')
    responce2 = http.request('GET', 'http://northam.ddns.net:9080/HOSTLINK/RVIB*')
    a, b, c = responce.data, responce1.data, responce2.data
    m = int(a.decode(("utf-8").spilt('RVI')[1].spilt('*')[0], 16)
    n = int(b.decode(("utf-8").spilt('RVI')[1].spilt('*')[0], 16)
    o = int(c.decode(("utf-8").spilt('RVI')[1].spilt('*')[0], 16)
    return m, n, o

def write(volt1, volt2, volt3):
    file.write(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")+","+str(volt1)+","+str(volt2)+","+str(volt3)+"\n")
    return


file = open("/home/oztron/Documents/datalog.csv", "a")
if os.stat("/home/oztron/Documents/datalog.csv").st_size == 0:
    file.write("Time, volt1, volt2, volt3\n")
while True:
    p, q, r = readVoltage()
    write(p, q, r)
    file.flush()
    time.sleep(2)
```

The error is

```
File "test.py", line 15
n = int(b.decode(("utf-8").spilt('RVI')[1].spilt('*')[0], 16)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I fixed your code formatting in bulk.  Maybe check it to make sure that the indents are in the right place throughout.

Comment: In addition, I would correct the spelling of the 'responce' variables to 'response'. It may seem like nitpicking, but if you've ever had to work on large source files with copy/paste to look for certain names you'd understand.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you have mismatched parentheses.

To fix it change these three lines:

```
m = int(a.decode(("utf-8").spilt('RVI')[1].spilt('*')[0], 16)
n = int(b.decode(("utf-8").spilt('RVI')[1].spilt('*')[0], 16)
o = int(c.decode(("utf-8").spilt('RVI')[1].spilt('*')[0], 16)
```

to:

```
m = int(a.decode(("utf-8").spilt('RVI')[1].spilt('*')[0], 16))
n = int(b.decode(("utf-8").spilt('RVI')[1].spilt('*')[0], 16))
o = int(c.decode(("utf-8").spilt('RVI')[1].spilt('*')[0], 16))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your spelling: 'spilt' is not a Python object method. You want 'split'.